# GoogleFit - HistoryClient daily step count data

Tags: google-fit

I am using the historyclient of the googlefit. I am looking for the steps , calories and distance aggregated data per day for last 15 to 30 days .
However, I am getting inconsistent results every time I make a call to the historyclient which normally not matches to the googleFit dashboard . Any code snippet to get a reliable and consistent data.

Also, how reliable is the historyclient compare to the healthconnect apis  newly launched

Thanks,
Nitin

Implementing the historyclient with aggregate_step_Delta. This is getting me the steps but always inconsisten with the googlefit dashboard;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello MNitin, are you using the native APIs or the Rest APIs?